# Angular Factories and Filters $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with AngularJS and have created a Module, which has a Factory and a Filter. The Factory gets a local json file translations) and the filter provides a function that returns a translated version of the text. So the code looks like the following;

```
angular
    .module('i18n', [])
    .factory('translationDataFact', ['$http', function($http){

        var t = {};
        var user = {};
        t.defaultLanguage = 'en-GB';
        t.languageFile = null;

        t.init = function(){
            t.setLanguage();
            if(!t.languageFile){
                $http
                    .get('translations/' + t.defaultLanguage + '.json')
                    .success(function(data){
                        t.languageFile = data.strings;
                    })
                    .error(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        }

        t.setLanguage = function(){
            /* change default language to User language here */
            if(user.id){
                t.defaultLanguage = user.language;
            }
            return t.defaultLanguage;
        }

        t.init();

        return t.languageFile;
    }])
    .filter('t', ['translationDataFact', function (translationDataFact) {

        var translate = function (stringIdenitfier) {

            var translation = translationDataFact.languageFile[stringIdenitfier];

            if(translation){
                return translation;
            }

            return "translate me!!";
        };

        return translate(stringIdenitfier);

    }]);
```

Then I wish to use the filter to translate variables and names like this

```
{{"string" | t }}
```

The problem I am having is that I have no idea how to make sure

1. The return of the Factory is set before the Filter runs this.
2. Also I am confused by how I prevent the whole application rendering until this filter is ready?

Any help would be amazing as I am lost :(

Comment: I think you mean `return t;` at the end of your factory.

Comment: I didn't think i needed all of t, i just returned the t.languageFile.

Comment: Then what you return is just `null`. Even after the callback has changed the value of `t.languageFile`, the returned value will still be `null`. You are returning a *value*, not a variable/reference.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you don't use an existing angularjs translation library like [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/)?

Comment: I had not seen this library, could I dynamically load my json from an external file with this language? I note there is a dynamic example but it does not look dynamic?

Comment: You can certainly ajax load the translations json file which I believe is shown in the dynamic example you have seen. If you are looking to load the translations from a resource external to your application you should be able to as I interpret the api docs here http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translateUrlLoader

Answer (score 0):

1. In factory method u need to return Service itself, not result of operation. (I am not sure what exactly u want from this serivce)
2. when you return t.language it is always null and it will remain null in your filter... because your http call is asynchronious.
3. I would make this like:

   app.module('translationDataFact', ['$resource', function($resource) {
   var t = {};
   t.init = function() {
         t.result = $resource('...');
   }
   t.init()
   return t; 
   }]);

In controller you have:
    $scope.language = translationDataFact.result;

You make filter with parameter, inside filter you can check whether language is undefined or not.
So later you write:

```
{{ "string" | t:language}
```

And after language 'arrives' you see translation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your concerns:

1. Your factory should return something that can be asked for a specific translation. If the translations are not ready just return something basic like an empty string or `null`. e.g.

   `return translations.t(languageFile, translationKey);`

   Where `t()` would be a function that inspects the internal data structure of `translations` and can return either the result of the translation or the value mentioned earlier if the translations haven't been loaded yet.
2. You can do something like `ng-show="translations.isLoaded()"` on your top level element, but you'd need to set up a reference to the `translations` service on the `$scope` of your highest level controller. You may want to do this on the `$rootScope` so your translation service is always available in controllers as well.